# Какую связь между таблицами лучше всего организовать?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица товаров. id, product.
Существует такая таблица. У каждого товара, может быть свой комплект. Как лучше всего оганизовать такую связь? Что я думал сделать.
Создать таблицу комплетк. id, tovar1, tovar2, tovar3, tovar4, tovar5. И просто прописать id связанных товаров в tovar1, tovar2 итд. Но что то не очень мне нравится такая схема, так же может быть не всегда 5 комплектов, может быть и 3 и 4. Что делать?

Comment: У товара может быть только один комплект?

Comment: нет может быть и 2 и 3. Например у кольца может быть сережки и цепочка

Comment: почитайте про связи многие-ко-многим, и создайте себе БД.

Comment: @duddeniska, тогда согласен с предыдущим комментарием: многие-ко-многим вам в помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Имеет смысл создать таблицу комплектов, в которой будут только его ID и, например, его название (`Sets(id, name)`). А также создать таблицу связей ("многие-ко-многим") товаров и комплектов, в которой будут поля `product_id` и `set_id` (и, при желании, `id`).
В таком случае вы сможете добавлять в комплекты любое количество товаров.

Comment: вот супер, помогли